# A and B flips a coin alternately. A starts. the one how gets `H` first - wins. what is the probability that B wins?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Giving the following question:

> A and B flips a cion, alternately. A starts.
>
> The one who gets `H` first, wins.
>
> Let X be a random variable denotes the number of flips at the end of the game.
>
> Calculate: $P(X is even)

I found two approached that yields two difference solutions:

> 1. Let A flips a coin , and Let B flip a coin. (Assume `A` didn't win)
>
> I'll call it a `round`. $round_i$ is independent.
>
> By a Tree, $P(A)_{head} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(B)_{head} = \frac{1}{4}$
>
> When $X$ is even, it's $B$'s round and therefore answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Second approch is simply:

> $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2})^{2i} \approx \frac{1}{3}$
>
> For each 2 flips, or for each round, we have a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ to get X even.

What is the right approach? If none of the above, that is the right approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you though about a Markov process with two absorbing states? (The "winning" states)

Comment: For your first approach, the tree continues for the remaining $\frac14$ chance.

Comment: This is a nested event structure. I think your second approach is correct, as it takes into account all of the events that have happenneed before it.

Also, I am not convinced whether you can say that two tosses of the coin that A and B throw are independent. (As they are happenning in succession, It is probably in correct to think of them to be independent)

Answer (score 1):

Using your first approach, and let $B$ has a probability of $p$ winning.

First $A$ flips, and has a $1\over2$ chance to win.

Then, given $A$ does not win yet, $B$ has a $1\over 2$ chance to win. i.e. the chance of $B$ winning when $X=2$ is $1\over4$.

Given $A$ and $B$ both do not win on their first flip, the game restarts and $B$ has a conditional probability $p$ to win.

Solve for $p = P(B \text{ wins}) =P(X\text{ is even})$:

$$p = P(X=2) + P(X>2)\cdot P(X\text{ is even}\mid X>2) = \frac14+\frac14p$$

Answer (score 0):

A simple logic would be that, since A tosses first, A is twice as likely to win as B.
$$P(A)+P(B)=1$$
$$2\times P(B)+P(B)=1$$
$$3\times P(B)=1$$
$$P(B)=\frac13$$

Comment: Assuming the coin is unbiased.